# AFNetworking in iOS application put request not working correctly

Tags: ios, afnetworking, put

I am trying to make a put request to be able to change the parameters I'm passing in and I'm getting a 400 error.

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), 
got 400" UserInfo=0x8a7d7d0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"messages":{"error":
[{"code":400,"message":"Server can not understand Content-Type HTTP header media type
\"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded\""}]}},
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest 
http://test.example.com/api/rest/customers/841>, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://test.example.com/api/rest/customers/841, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400, 
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8a7e1e0>}
```

This is the code I have for my request.

```
 ExampleHTTPClient *sharedClient = [ExampleHTTPClient sharedClient];
    NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"email":@"example@gmail.com",@"firstname":@"Bob", @"lastname":@"Jones"};

    [sharedClient setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];

    [sharedClient putPath:@"/api/rest/customers/841" parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];
```

I'm new to working with web service so my problem is understanding what is going on.

Any help or thoughts are appreciated and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't explain your issue when I setup a `AFNetworking` client I used the following:

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass: [AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[self setDefaultHeader: @"Accept"
                 value: @"application/json"];
```

where `self` was an instance of a subclass of `AFHTTPClient`.

The HTTP Status Code of 400 is: 'Bad Request - The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.'  Do you have access to the server logs to see that structure of the request?